# How to read an eigen matrix from a file?

Tags: c++, file, file-io, eigen, eigen3

I know I can write an eigen matrix to a file like this:

```
  std::ofstream file("test.txt");
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 1, Eigen::DontAlign> m;
    m << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
    file << m;
  }
```

Whats the easiest way to read it again? This does not seem to work:

```
  std::ifstream file("test.txt");
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 1, Eigen::DontAlign> m;
    file >> m;
  }
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
error: cannot bind 'std::basic_istream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_istream<char>&&'
         file >> m;
```

Comment: You need to define an overload of `operator>£()` that takes your `Eigen` class.

Answer (score -1):

Initialize each element individually:

```
#include <fstream>

Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 1, Eigen::DontAlign> m;
std::ifstream file("test.txt");
if (file.is_open()) {
    file >> m(0) >> m(1) >> m(2) >> m(3) >> m(4);
}
```

Use loops for larger matrices.